# H264/MP4 live stream from ffmpeg does not work in browser

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, live-streaming, video-encoding

I cannot visualize a H264/MP4 stream generated by ffmpeg in Chrome, IE, Edge. It works only in Firefox.

My testing environment is Windows 10, all updates done, all browsers up to date.

I have a source MJPEG stream, which I need to transcode to H264/MP4 and show it in browser in a HTML5 element.
In order to provide a working example, I use here this MJPEG stream: http://200.36.58.250/mjpg/video.mjpg?resolution=320x240. In my real case I have MJPEG input from different sources like IP cameras.
I use the following command line:

ffmpeg.exe -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f mjpeg -i "http://200.36.58.250/mjpg/video.mjpg?resolution=320x240" -f mp4 -c:v libx264 -an -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart -reset_timestamps 1 -vsync 1 -flags global_header -r 15 "tcp://127.0.0.1:5000?listen"

If I try to visualize the output in VLC, I use this link: tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 and it works.
Then I try to visualize the stream in browser, so I put this into a html document:

```
<video autoplay controls>
<source src="http://127.0.0.1:5000" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If I open the document in Firefox it works just fine.
But it does not work when trying to open in Chrome, IE or Edge. It seems that the browser tries to connect to the TCP server exposed by ffmpeg, but something happens because ffmpeg exits after few seconds.

In ffmpeg console I can see this:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error
Error writing trailer of tcp://127.0.0.1:5000?listen: Error number -10053 occurred
```

If I inspect the video element in Chrome is can see this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

As far as I know all these browsers should support H264 encoded streams transported in MP4 containers. If in the element I replace the link http://127.0.0.1:5000 with a local link to a mp4/H264 encoded file, it is played just fine in each browser. The problem seems to be related to live streaming.

Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be solved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just outputting to a TCP socket.  That's not HTTP.  Browsers speak HTTP... you need to use an HTTP server in this case.

Comment: Are there more details to get this setup working? i.e. what is the command line for FFMPEG and also where does the HTTP server fit into the setup? Thank you

Comment: @bilogic The FFmpeg output can be `-` to output to STDOUT.  Then, a basic HTTP server setup (like via Node.js) can run FFmpeg as a child process and pipe its output directly to the requesting client.

Comment: thanks, what kind of client (chrome?) and latency can I expect from this? I'm looking for something low latency, I was able to achieve 4 seconds with an audio only HLS. Looking for something even more realtime.

Comment: @bilogic I've had latencies as low as a couple hundred milliseconds.  If you're interested, I have example code you can license for your project.  Please e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co either way... I can help you make sure you're using the right tech for your use case.  As you've seen, HLS isn't great for lower latency streaming.  Regular HTTP progressive can work fine, but it may require some handling client-side to catch back up to realtime if the stream drops out.  WebRTC is tuned end-to-end for latency at the expense of quality and reliability.

Comment: thanks, but what I'm doing here isn't commercial, I'm basically streaming audio from my room to the internet to identify a nuisance noise, 4 seconds is "just acceptable". I just wanted to arm them with the technology to be able to tell in realtime if the device they are looking at is the source of the noise. So it had to be browser based for ease of use + low latency.

Comment: In that case, maybe just a simple Google Hangout or something would work fine?  Or any other WebRTC-based chat.  You can also use Icecast with a very low buffer size as your server, and that will get you in the 2-second range, assuming the connection is good.  Set `preload="none"` on your audio tag client-side.

Comment: I want a page that the simplest user can operate and I can easily support. Anyway, I managed to route ffmpeg to vlc to chrome, but still ~4s delay, tweaking it now, not sure if due to mp3 format, trying ogg. Command is ffmpeg -re -f dshow -rtbufsize 10M -i audio="Microphone (3- High Definition Audio Device)" -filter:a "highpass=f=380, lowpass=f=420, highpass=f=380, lowpass=f=420, volume=10" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f mp3 pipe:1 | vlc -vvv - :live-caching=300 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=mp3,dst=:8181/stream} :sout-keep

Comment: added the preload="none" as suggested. what does it do btw? thanks!

<video id="video" controls="controls" preload="none" src="http://localhost:8181/humming" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora" autoplay="autoplay">